# Calling copyPixels from a large BitmapData sometimes costs 200-300ms

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to get a small [BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) (about 500x500) from a big BitmapData (about 2000x4000) with the [copyPixels](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels()) method. During each frame, I'll get one small BitmapData with a copyPixels call.

In one frame, lag becomes very high. Using Adobe Scout CC, I found that "UnCompress Image" was costing 200-300ms, but in some other frame.  As it didn't happen when I called copyPixels with small source BitmapData, I guess the reason is that the source BitmapData was too big? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you uncompress the image once and call copypixels on that?

Comment: use draw instead it's faster.

Comment: @Brian I get the source bitmapdata by load a png file then get the content of the loader. I'm not sure if UnCompress Image happens when the copypixels is called, so I can't  uncompress the image once.

Comment: Do you monitor memory? This can be caused by running a GC.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not an answer to your question. This is to illustrate the fact, that there is no apparent problem with `copyPixels()`. This is a simple standalone test, you can copy and paste it into a new project and see what happens (just place the image in question into output folder). I stripped the test of anything time-consuming except for `copyPixels()`.

It appears that the problem is somewhere else and more info on the problem is required.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    [SWF(backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF", width="1024", height="768", frameRate="60")]
    public class StackCopyPixels extends Sprite
    {
        private var sourceImage:BitmapData;
        private var loader:Loader;
        private var targetImage:BitmapData;
        private var timeLabel:TextField;
        private var log:String = "";
        private var count:int = 0;
        private var sizeLimit:int;
        private var sourceRect:Rectangle;
        private var destPoint:Point;

        public function StackCopyPixels()
        {
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
            // in my case the image is 3450x720, so it's bigger than BitmapData limit of 2880 px
            // (which I figured could be the source of the problem)
            loader.load(new URLRequest("image.png"));

            targetImage = new BitmapData(500, 500, true, 0);
            addChild(new Bitmap(targetImage));

            timeLabel = new TextField();
            timeLabel.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            timeLabel.background = true;
            timeLabel.multiline = true;
            timeLabel.wordWrap = false;
            addChild(timeLabel);
        }

        protected function onImageLoaded(event:Event):void
        {
            var image:Bitmap = loader.content as Bitmap;
            sourceImage = image.bitmapData;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
            sizeLimit = Math.floor(sourceImage.width/targetImage.width);
            sourceRect = targetImage.rect;
            destPoint = new Point();
        }

        protected function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
        {
            var s:int = getTimer();

            sourceRect.x = (count%sizeLimit)*500;
            sourceRect.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(sourceImage.height-sourceRect.height));
            targetImage.copyPixels(sourceImage, sourceRect, destPoint);

            var elapsed:int = getTimer()-s;
            if (elapsed > (1000/60*2)) {
                log += "\nslow at "+count+" (position "+(count%sizeLimit)+"): "+elapsed;
            }
            timeLabel.text = elapsed.toString()+log;

            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is the solution (it is difficult to tell as we don't have additional information from your side, but consider this:

Every time you 'use' an image, it needs to be decompressed. Even if you maintain it's bitmapData. As funny as it sounds. So let's assume you want to display (or even access an image) that you have just loaded. Flash will take the image, decompress it (very probably that's the hit you are experiencing) and display it or call the method on it's bitmapData. The decoding stuff takes various time depending on the size of the bitmap.

This is unacceptable in many situations, so you can check here for a workaround: [Keeping Bitmaps Decompressed](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2105). The idea there is to simply "ping" the bitmapData or perform some method on it every X seconds so the Flash runtime doesn't release it from the memory (it releases it only if the image is not displayed somewhere on the display list), otherwise it will have to decompress it again. Or you could just display the image on the display list... in that case it is definitely decompressed.

I have ran into the same issue myself (showing like 150 HD images in a sequence) - the first run was always choppy, the consecutive runs were ok if the animation was not stopped as being stopped cleared them from the memory. The method with accessing the pixel in the bitmaps worked flawlessly (even tho I implemented it a bit differently; I didn't read that article in that time yet).